# Error thrown when try to add project to tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-indigo

I created a maven project but when I try to add it to my server I receive this error :

[image]

I converted the project to a 'Dynamic Web Project' by updating its facet. Is there something else I missed ?

Comment: Looks like bad Maven and Eclipse dependencies.

Comment: @duffymo maybe the question should be 'how to create a maven dynamic web project' ?

Comment: I have no idea, it's your question.  My recommendation?  Leave out all the stuff you don't understand - Maven and Eclipse - and see if you can create a WAR file that successfully deploys on Tomcat without them.  Simplify.

Comment: @user470184, did you know you can set your own name by [editing your profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/470184)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing facets has proven ugly from time to time. Even changing an existing dynamic web project (one of its facets, e.g. Dynamic web module from 2.5 to 2.6) gives a lot of trouble.

Advice: leave aside Maven -for a while- and start a new dynamic web project from scratch. Import the sources you need (don't copy them, import them, found it to be a good practice with control version environments). Associate  a server to the project and try to deploy it.